Simulate random packet drop on RDMA Mellanox NIC
I know I can simulate random packet drop with
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem loss 50%

But how to simulate packet drop when using RDMA on Mellanox ConnextX-7 NIC?
RDMA has kernel bypass so the solution above does not work. The RoCE UDP packet is processed directly on the NIC.
